# How to terminate the 3 pairs coming from 66 block into suite for POTS line

Tags: telephony

ATT put a note on the 66 block for this telephone line that says "Ground this pair" and the note was on the blue/blue white pair.  However the 2 pairs that are punched down on the 66 block are the green/white green and orange/orangewhite pairs. All of these pairs are in one cat5 cable that leads down to the suite. 
At the suite, there is a red and white cable coming from somewhere and it is tied into the pairs mentioned above via metal tabs and then attached to wall plate as shown in photo. Phone has dial tone, but doesn't ring when called. Phone can call out and user can be heard, but can't hear. This is clearly rigged oddly and I would like to just use cat5 without red/white, but I don't know what they are there for? Any ideas?[image: 1]      [image: 2]

Comment: You only need one pair for a POTS line.  If you get dial tone, you should have a good line.  One way audio could be a different problem -- maybe a problem with the phone.  If no ring, are you sure you're dialing the right number?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you should do:

1. Pick up the line that is currently working and run ANI (Automatic Number Identification) on it. At the time of this writing, you can do ANI in North America by calling 1-800-444-4444 from the line you want to know the number of. It sounds like you are going to find that the number you get from ANI is not the same as the number you think you should have on this line. Let's assume that is the case. Then:
2. Call AT&T (assuming you are paying them for the line in question) and ask them to do a "tag and locate" in the demarc for the line you want to have working. They should send out a tech to basically hang a little tag in the demarc on the pair (as Ron commented, jut one pair for a POTS line) that has the line on it. Then you should be cross-connect that pair up to your suite if you have a 66 tool and the will and knowledge to use it.

If you're not sure about doing your own cross-connects or any part of this doesn't make sense to you, then I **highly** recommend you ask AT&T or hire a third-party wiring contractor to "extend the demarc" into your suite for this line. One thing I've done in the past is estimated how long it will take me to  cross-connect a line after a tag & locate, multiplied that by my salary hourly equivalent, and if that cost is higher than getting the provider to extend the demarc, I just ask them to do it and bill us.